# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^n}$ for $n=0,1,2,\dots$

Tags: limits

Hints as to where to start with this? Feel like it's something with the squeeze theorem but don't inherently see the answer. For $n=0,1,2,\dots$ compute the limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^n}$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, and $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^n}=\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2\frac{x^2}{x^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the taylor series of sin(x) has smallest degree of 1 (x-x^3/6+x^5/120...)
The expansion of sin^2 has smallest degree of 2. Thus, for n<2, sin^2(x)/x^n→0
for n=2, sin^2(x)/x^n→1 and for n>2 sin^2(x)/x^n→∞

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset equations.